# Rather small bitmap returns invalid parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, resolution

**EDIT - Solved?**

After restarting VS... The exception seems to have COMPLETELY dissappeared. It just doesn't occur anymore. Sooo... Problem solved? I suppose?

**OP**

In my application, I am trying to create a bitmap of size `1366 x 706`. However, when I attempt to paint it onto my form, it returns a `"parameter is not valid"` exception.

After reading up, I learned that the parameter error usually means that C# won't allocate enough memory for the bitmap. However, `1366x706` doesn't seem to be that large of a resolution.

On disk, a `1366x706` image only takes up `2.5MB`. Is that too large for `WinForms` to handle?

**EDIT**

Code:

```
// These variables vary based on the size of the winform, these values return the error 
float resizeFactorX = 4.553333f;
float resizeFactorY = 2.353333f;

// The original size of the image is ALWAYS 300x300, that never changes
public static Image resizeImageByFactors(Image i, float resizeFactorX, float resizeFactorY)
{
    Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap((int)((float)(i.Width) * resizeFactorX), (int)((float)(i.Height * resizeFactorY)));
    using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1))
    {
        gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        gr.DrawImage(i, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, new Size(bitmap1.Width, bitmap1.Height)));
    }
    return bitmap1;
}
```

If you need any more information, don't hesitate to let me know.

**EDIT 2**

The error is also produced anytime the resize factors are not equal to 1.0.

Stack Trace:

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height)
at Paint_Test.Form1.resizeImageByFactors(Image i, Single resizeFactorX, Single     resizeFactorY) in c:\Users\ApachePilotMPE\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Paint     Test\Paint Test\Form1.cs:line 273
```

Comment: The size certainly isn't too large.  Please show your code.

Comment: Added the code to the OP

Comment: Which line throws the errors? Post the stacktrace if you can.

Comment: Did you check the results of casting floats to ints are correct?

Comment: @HenkHolterman the line that throws the error is the Bitmap declaration.

Comment: @Aybe the casts work just fine.

Comment: The code looks to work, tried on my machine with a picture of the same size and it works fine. Btw, the float casts are redundant. What line specifically errors?

Comment: Put a Debug stop on that line and look at the numbers.  They are probably not what you think they are.

Comment: `float resizeFactorX = 4.553333;` won't compile, that makes the rest suspicious/unreliable as well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman why won't it compile? Those numbers were from the Debug output from floats which were changed by the application.

Comment: @HenkHolterman those were probably just shown to demonstrate the values

@ApachePilotMPE you can declare the values like `float resizeFactorX = 4.553333f;` in the future to demonstrate it's a float, without the f, VS treats it as a double.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm not used to declaring values with floating points outright, most of them are defined as `float resizeFactorX = (float)(this.ClientSize.Width / 300.0);` or similar.

Comment: Either way, the posted code doesn't produce the error for your audience.  Either the numbers are out of whack or your image isn't valid.  Something we can't see.

Comment: AFAIK Bitmap objects must be created with integers, not floating numbers. Although I doubt this is your actual problem (casting should occur automatically), you may want to review your design.

Comment: Also, even though at first sight it doesn't seem possible, you'd be wise to assert that size values aren't negative numbers.

Comment: The purpose of this code is to resize an image based on the ClientSize of the form. It is part of an application which has a set of images in an array [50, 50]. The images are displayed based on a point which is altered by pressing the arrow keys. The error always occurs when the form  is larger than default (300, 300).

Comment: Am I to understand that a bitmap instance is created every time the form is resized? Is this bitmap always properly disposed of after being painted? Sorry if it sounds like a stupid question, I'm trying to eliminate possibilities here :)

Comment: The bitmap is always disposed. I've found that the application throws this error anytime a bitmap larger than the ClientSize of the form is created. Is that something you've seen before? EDIT: check that, the error also occurs when undisposed bitmaps are created in a loop. I'll check my code for places I can dispose images. Also, the bitmap in the resizeImageByFactors() gets disposed when the function ends, correct? To make sure I'm not misinformed?

Comment: Maybe you should post your Resize event code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Actually given where the exception occurs the form context is quite irrelevant if, as you say, the created bitmaps always are disposed of correctly. I really can't understand what the problem could be.

Comment: @LarsTech There is no code which occurs when the resize event ticks.

Comment: When the program bombs, you should be able to see what the values are for the Image i width and height, and the refactor values, too.

Comment: @LarsTech I've already checked those, they always seem to fit the context, I've never had any values which which don't work in the program. Also, any time AT ALL in the program that a bitmap is declared now seems to have the possibility of throwing the error.

Comment: I'm going to do some research into the cause of it on my own. I'll report back when I find a solution.

Comment: Watch out here: "resizeFactorX = (float)(this.ClientSize.Width / 300.0);" You must cast to float before the division, or your result will be 0 if Width < 300.0 !

Answer (score 1):

> "Either way, the posted code doesn't produce the error for your
>   audience. Either the numbers are out of whack or your image isn't
>   valid. Something we can't see. – LarsTech"

Well, it seems that your error have nothing to do with the code that you have posted here.

I think it is related with how you are calculating the XY resize factors. If you are still doing this:

```
resizeFactorX = (float)(this.ClientSize.Width / 300.0);
```

**You will get 0 if Width < 300**!

As you said:

> "I've found that the application throws this error anytime **a bitmap
>   larger than the ClientSize** of the form is created"

This happens because Width is an int, and you are casting after the int/float division, that results an int. You must cast the int to float BEFORE the division.

Correct way:

```
resizeFactorX = ((float)this.ClientSize.Width) / 300;
```

I hope this solves your problem. :)